# How do you increment a knockout.js observable?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm finding this a strange place to be at a bit of a loss, but if I cant' do this:

```
koObserv(koObserv() + 1);
```

and a method is not provided, am I forced to do:

```
koObserv = ko.observable(koObserv() + 1)
```

This seems really clumsy.. is there another way that I'm missing?

Comment: You can do `koObserv(koObserv() + 1);`.  Can you share your code where this is not working?  The only place where this can cause problems, is if it is in a computed observable where it can cause recursive re-evaluation.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates incrementing:

http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/LbPDK/

As you can see `self.num(self.num() + 1);` does work.

Answer (score 11):

you could abstract these logic into an extend observable

```
ko.observable.fn.increment = function (value) {
    this(this() + (value || 1));
};

var counter = ko.observable(0);
console.log(counter()); // 0

counter.increment();
console.log(counter()); // 1

counter.increment();
console.log(counter()); // 2

counter.increment(5);
console.log(counter()); // 7
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to, if you use a lot of increment, create some helper function to do the increment and pass it the reference of your observable. You end up with more readable code.

**JS**:

```
var increment = function (observable) {
    observable(observable() + 1);
};

var MyViewModel = function () {
    this.num1 = ko.observable(0);

    this.incrementNum = function (observable) {
        // passing the observable by reference to the helper function
        increment(observable);
    }
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<button data-bind="click: incrementNum.bind($root, num1)">
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/rafaeleyng/ddtsvb0n/)

Comment: You can also add a function to the [`ko.observable.fn`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/fn.html)